# Typos in API documentation

Tags: bug, api, wording

> When constructing filters, you need to be aware of this distinction as excluding properties on `user` does not exclude then on `shallow_users` , and vice versus.

<sup>([User Types](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-types))</sup>

1. There should be a comma after *distinction*.
2. *Then* should be *them*.
3. There should be no space before the comma after *shallow_users*.
4. The sentence should end with *vice versa*, not *vice versus*.

Comment: There should be a comma after discussion? There is only one word "discussion" on that page, and there certainly shouldn't be a comma after it...

Comment: Sorry. Me stupid. Fixed.